# Greek Characters in Julia Jupyter edition

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, visual-studio-code, ijulia-notebook

I am using Julia.

I am trying to get some greek characters in Jupyter notebooks.

First I downloaded the latest version of Julia 1.6.2

For the jupyter connection I used anaconda, in julia repl i put `] add IJulia`, and then I could chose the Julia kernel in Jupyter.

Then a friend suggested to download vs code (since we got a problem in the working directory with jupyter-anaconda)

In VS code we got no problem with working directories. And to work with notebooks we installed the Jupyter extension. It was working very well, but we got to this problem that we cannot get greek characters.

In Jupyter (anaconda) I could easily put greek characters, like this:

[image]

no package needed, nothing, just like that.

However in VSCode I cannot get that, nor "predictive text" or coding suggestions:

[image]

Any tips on how to solve this?

Like we are preferring VS Code and we know there's a way to get the greek characters on it, but we don't know how.

Any help is very welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me out of the box. Have you connected your VSCode notebook to the Julia kernel? If so the autocomplete should offer you the completion.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to install the Julia for VS code extension?

Comment: @niczky12 How can I do that?

Comment: ty bois/girls for all the help

Comment: On the top right corner of an ipynb notebook in VSCode, you should see a `select kernel` button. Click this and then select Julia from the drop-down menu in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs for the Julia extension in VS code here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/julia. Per the comments above, make sure this is installed and you have the Julia kernel selected. You should then see the following:

[image: Alpha symbol tab completion in VS Code]